# R - Count the Number of 6s in a Variable

Tags: r, probability, montecarlo

I am trying to write an algorithm that will allow me to calculate the probability of rolling a six on a variable number of dice.  Here is what I have:

```
num.dice <- 6

## x is the number of iterations

x <- 1
a <- c()
while(x < 1000) {
  a[(x:x)] <- sum(sample(1:6, num.dice, replace=TRUE)==1)
  x <- x + 1
}
sum(a)/1000
```

I would prefer to use a monte carlo style simulation, but I believe I cannot get the count of 6s right.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my math is a bit rusty, but is this what you are looking for?

```
library( gtools )

num_dice <- 1:6

lapply(num_dice, function(x) {
  sum( 
    apply( 
      permutations( 6, x, 1:6, repeats.allowed = TRUE ), 
      1, 
      function(y) any( y == 6 ) 
      ) 
    ) / 6^x
})

[[1]]
[1] 0.1666667

[[2]]
[1] 0.3055556

[[3]]
[1] 0.4212963

[[4]]
[1] 0.5177469

[[5]]
[1] 0.5981224

[[6]]
[1] 0.665102
```

Comment: equivalent one-liner for calculation (1 - P(no 6 in rolls)): `1 - ((5/6) ^ (1:6))`